# Mac OS X 10.8.2, retina display: change DPI

Tags: macos, mac, dpi, macbook-pro-retina

I have a MacBook Pro, 15", Retina display.

It's great, really fantastic, but some older apps aren't "retina-aware" or "hidpi-aware".  However, since the res is massive, I'd like to be able to take advantage of the large amount of screen space.

I have tried the following:

- Edit the package and .plist file to make the app high-resolution aware: this made the app (Pro Tools 8) have some non-aliased text, but UI was the same size
- Under Display, change the mode to a Scaled one, the option at the end with the 'most space': this worked, but there was a noticeable performance hit, the app text was still aliased (pixellated), though smaller
- Installed the Quartz Debug tool and used "User Interface Resolution".  However the latest version doesn't have a DPI slider, just a "Enable high DPI resolutions" check box, which is checked [and unchecking it does nothing]

Basically if I could convince Mac OS X that the attached display isn't retina, or has a DPI of 96, there would be no scaling, and everything would be as I want (albeit it small and close to unreadable - I can work around that).

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just change the resolution directly?

I utility is available from here which will allow you to specify the exact resolution.

http://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/vi9yf/set_your_retina_macbook_pros_resolution_to/

To look the exact same as a non-retina, but high-resolution, 15 inch Macbook Pro, you want the resolution to be 1680x1050.

Comment: -1 The OP wans apps to utilise the full resolution (look small but sharp).

Comment: The mentioned application will let you set the resolution to the full 2880x1800 resolution, as well.  This is 1:1 mapping between physical pixels and software pixels.

Comment: @kinokijuf - Mind removing the downvote?

Comment: @ZachR No, because you have misleading information in your answer.

Comment: @kinokijuf as the asker of the question, I can confirm his answer is correct and not at all misleading.  Remove the downvote..

Comment: @KierenJohnstone by “misleading information”, I mean the mention of the 1680x1050 resolution.